# Recurring Error on NFT Art generator script, index.js: DNA Exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, nft

I can't find line where DNA is called, before I added some lines of code the code was executing just fine.
Now the error is running and won't let me quit the execution.

Here is the line where Dna is created on index.js. I see it calls for variable races and race but I don't know how races makes the dna

```js
    const createDna = (_races, _race) => {
      let randNum = [];
      _races[_race].layers.forEach((layer) => {
        let randElementNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        let num = 0;
        layer.elements.forEach((element) => {
          if (randElementNum >= 100 - element.weight) {
            num = element.id;
          }
    });
        randNum.push(num);
      });
      return randNum;
    };
```

Then, in config.js the variable _races appears here. I don't know if what follows from the rest of the code is important for your answer, but this is what I've got so far...

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const width = 708;
const height = 1080;
const dir = __dirname;
const description = "This is an NFT made by the coolest generative code.";
const baseImageUri = "https://hashlips/nft";
const startEditionFrom = 1;
const endEditionAt = 34;
const editionSize = 34;
const raceWeights = [
  {
    value: "skull",
    from: 1,
    to: editionSize,
  },
];

const races = {
  skull: {
    name: "skull",
    layers: [
      {
        name: "Background",
        elements: [
          {
            id: 0,
            name: "Light pink",
            path: `${dir}/1-background/PRDE_0008s_0000_Capa-5.png`,
            weight: 100,
          },
]
         // etc...
]

}
```

When I break the execution, the process exits with this message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'layers')
```

and it only produces 24 layers of pngs out of the total 34 I asked it to produce. What's wrong?

Comment: I must say this code I copied from a github user on youtube, I know the basics of javascript, but the connection of races with dna is what bums me. please provide help i beg!!!!

Comment: So fn I have only seen that DNA is a set of numbers so: `PS C:\Users\yoona\OneDrive\Documents\generative-art-opensource-4> node index.js
Created edition: 1, Race: skull with DNA: 0,1,6,0,2,3,2,5,3` that make a png unique. Just I don't know how to maximise the editionSize of the collection.

Comment: MAybe all I want to know is if I could've installed Truffle wrong.